# How to write a function that adds certain amount for every increment of 1000 in php

Tags: php

Here I have total sales worth RM 3500.

I need to give points to every 1000 in that 3500.The point value is 0.1 and it should increase in same value for every subsequent increment.

So, In the example above, in RM 3500. I have 3 x 1000.
The first 1000 get 0.1 point. The next 1000 gets 0.2 and the third gets 0.3 and so on. Anything below 1000 will not make any changes.How do I write this as a function in PHP?

I can only think of if else statement but this is not efficient.

```
//default
$increament = 0.1;

//calculate increament
        if($new_sales == 1000)
        {
            $increment +=0.1; 
        }...after this I don't know how to write for subsequent 1000
```

Comment: Is it just assigning the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$increment = (floor(3500/1000)/10);
```

or

```
$increment = (floor(3500/1000)*0.1);
```

from your code:

```
$increment = (floor($new_sales/1000)*$increament);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the sales total and divide by 1000, round down and multiply by 0.1.

```
$increment = floor($new_sales / 1000) * 0.01;
```

Comment: @But Tristan, this also counts accordingly for value below 1000... I got increment 2.5

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understood it correctly:

```
<?php
    $points = 0;
    $startingPoint = 0.1;
    if($new_sales >= 1000)
    {
        $increment = floor($new_sales/1000);
        // 3500 / 1000 --> 3
        for($i = 0;i <= $increment;$i++)
        {
            $points += $startingPoint * $i;
            // ex. points += 0.1 * 1
            //     points += 0.1 * 2
        }
    }
?>
```